# writing lambda expression in VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, lambda, c#-to-vb.net

I need to write this as lambda in VB.net

```
foos.Select(o => new Bar().InjectFrom(o));
```

Please help me.

When I write, the editor automatically makes it as  (> and then =) I am confused if its correct?

```
foos.Select(o >= new Bar().InjectFrom(o));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foos.Select(Function(o) New Bar().InjectFrom(o))`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tried, however, damn, it says BAR is not a delgate type and can not be converted :( Please help me

Comment: Basically, I want to do target.injectfrom(source)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with AutoMapper to help you with those specific classes. Sorry. I can assure you that the C# lambda you put in the question is the equivalent to the VB.NET one I wrote. Make sure you have the right namespaces imported is the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: I agree with you. However, I need to know how to map using value injector :( OMU claims its easy to map than automapper, ut I find this to be complicated than automapper